# Can't use texture draw on an object

Tags: modeling, modifiers, uv, texture-painting, subdivision-surface

I'm following Blender Guru's tutorial Donut series.

After completing the modelling and sculpting I noticed I had more than one million polygons, so I reduced it by using Decimate modifier. After that, I couldn't Texture Paint on the mesh. There are some lines and when I try to draw on them, the lines appear in the hall area.

Here is the link to my [Blender file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/oswV69WD/)
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: have your checked the normals? Maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your unwrap was probably bad, you must have had faces overlapping in your UVmap, I've redone it:

- Select the whole mesh in *Edit* mode, switch to *Face Select* mode, select one last face to make it active, press <kbd>U</kbd> *(Unwrap) > Follow Active Quads*:

[image]

- Paint:

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU for solving, now Texture Paint works perfectly