# Texture glitched

Tags: modeling, texturing, modifiers, uv, texture-painting

I was following Blender Guru's tutorial just fine until I started having issues painting the texture of the donut.

I have tried creating a new brush and texture, some fixes about the UV mapping. Nothing works, but I believe the issue is with the UV mapping.
Because if I try [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/193653/cant-use-texture-draw-on-the-donut),
it kind of gets fixed and the texture repeats for every face on the donut.

Any directions? Here is [the donut and the texture](https://filebin.net/obi7roprkljodxlb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to unwrap your donut (go in *Edit* mode, select all and choose the *Smart UV Project* mode), then paint in *Solid* or *Material Preview* display mode. It looks like in Cycles you can't see a direct result of your painting in *Render* mode, you need to save your image to see it (needs confirmation).

From what I understand you prefer to paint in the *Image Editor* rather than in the 3D view, in that case you need to choose another unwrap method, like for example with seams. First you need to select the edges that will be your seams, press <kbd>U</kbd> > *Mark Seam*:

[image]

Then move and rotate the UV in the *UV Editor* the way you want, you can square it with the *UV Squares* addon:

[image]

Then paint on the image in the *Image Editor* window. But note that you'll have to make correct joints where the seams happen, so it may need some corrections in *Texture Paint* mode in the 3D view.

Comment: Yes that worked, I can see my painting now. A new problem has unfortunately surfaced, the painting is not appearing in the correct way. Let me show you:   https://filebin.net/2dp2rg9133rslqfj

Comment: It appears that theres a uv mapping (?) over the image to be painted, and if i rotate that, the painting's direction changes too. But it wont appear correctly no matter how i rotate it and enlarge it.

Comment: it worked fine for me, maybe recalculate the normals (select all in Edit mode and press Shift N), if it still doesn't work, please share your file again

Comment: I tried that, ticked Inside but I dont see anything different. Here https://filebin.net/ko09tkmvu0s17uou

Comment: it works for me, what do you mean when you say that the painting direction changes?

Comment: Oh ok maybe you're trying to paint in the Image Editor, you need to paint in the 3D view instead, not in the Image Editor, if you want to paint in the Image Editor, you need to change the unwrap method to get a UV that will work, like unwrap with seams

Comment: i meant that when rotating the map circled, the painting's direction changes too at the donut, from appearing vertically to diagonally lets say .  https://filebin.net/26mm37ggx343g79y

Comment: what I was recommending was to paint in the 3D view, if you want to paint in the Image Editor you need to choose another unwrap method as I explain in my edit, see my answer

Comment: I think i will go with painting in 3d instead lol. Tenks <3